# Prevent xi:include processing

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Using XSL 3.0, I am copying an XML document and finding and replacing a certain piece of information. Everything works fine using this:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//foo">
 ...some action on foo here...
</xsl:template>
```

However, the original `xml` file has `<xi:include/>` to very large `xml` files and the copying process is 'opening' those `xml` files and inserting them into the copy 'whole' or 'expanded'.

I want to preserve the original `<xi:include/>`, not process it.

How do I instruct the XSLT file not to process `<xi:include/>`, but rather just copy the element and attribute(s)?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it would be useful to know what XSLT processor you do use.

Comment: I am using Saxon HE 9.6, within Oxygen and in command line (on Mac OS).

Comment: I doubt it is the copying process that opens the referenced files, that already happens when parsing the input document. As for Saxon from the command line, you can toggle the XInclude use on or off with `-xi:(on|off)` https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/using-xsl/commandline.html

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. But is there a way to include this as an instruction within the XSLT file? It seems to me to be something controllable within the templates?

Comment: It is the XML parser (used by the XSLT processor) which does any XInclude processing so that is not something you control in a template.

Comment: @idjet If I understand you right, you do not want <xi:include/> be copied with others elements and attributes. Then just add to your code as below:  <xsl:template match="xi:include"/>  it will avoid copying this element.

Comment: @O.F. Rather no, I just don't want it processed. Martin Honnen's suggestion worked for command line. It turns out in Oxygen there is a way of turning off xi:include processing in Preferences - but it's very clumsy as it is an Oxygen-level preference...one has to turn it off to process a file and then on again.

Answer (score 1):

An `xi:include` element will never be expanded by the XSLT processor, but it may be expanded in the course of building the tree that acts as input to the XSLT processor. Typically (though not necessarily) the thing that prepares this tree is an XML parser. Some XML parsers (but not all) have the ability to expand `xi:include` directives in the course of parsing. Where Saxon is in control of the parsing process, the `-xi` switch (or equivalents in the various APIs) can be used to enable `xi:include` processing by the parser, if supported. This switch is always off by default, but if `xi:include` processing has been requested in some other way (unknown to Saxon) then Saxon won't switch it off. For example, if you supply a `SAXSource` as the Saxon input, then it all depends on how you choose to configure the XML parser (`XMLReader`) in the `SAXSource` object.

If you're running Saxon within a third-party application such as oXygen or Stylus Studio, then you'll need to investigate how to control the parsing process in that environment.